# Cypress can't include value from outside in .get() function in custom command

Tags: typescript, cypress

I want to create a custom parent command in Cypress with get() function inside. I need to provide the locator of the element from the outside of the custom command. Here is my code.

```js
// cypress>support>commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('testCommand', (testVariable) => {
    cy.get(testVariable).click();
})
```

Because I am using TypeScript I need to add the command inside the index.ts

```js
// cypress>support>index.ts

testCommand(): Chainable<Element>
```

But when I want to call this custom command - I am not able to provide any parameter inside the function.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to define all the parameters for you custom command in the TypeScript definition:

```js
// cypress>support>index.ts

testCommand(testVariable: string): Chainable<Element>
```

Comment: Facepalm... of course. I forget to declare the parameter into the index.ts class. Thank you very much.